# Private Media Using Google Cloud CDN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, media, cdn

I have an application that uses the google bucket to store media, as there are many media, it was necessary to use the CDN service to reduce latency when loading them. However, when I use the CDN, the media is public and accessible to any unauthenticated person. Is there any way to cache the media and at the same time keep it private through an authentication token?

I tried in many ways following the documentation, keeping the Cache Type capturing the information from the Cache-Control header and the authorization token, but after caching the media it is accessible without the authentication token.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/private-content

Answer (score 1):

To add details to the link shared by John Hanley, using [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls)  will cache the content and at the same time, keep the access private to your stored media. You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#creatingkeys) for a more detailed procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to include the auth header as part of the cache key?  This would require the origin server to have auth functionality.

This would enable the object to be put into cache when the key is present.  Also, only a request with the auth header can retrieve the object from cache.

If a user without the key, or an incorrect key, attempts to get the file, it will be cache miss.  The origin server should then authenticate the header and thus no allow the object to be delivered.